# Different ways to tar in Linux

Tags: linux, tar

Guys can you take a look at the following:

```
tar cf foo.tar foo/ bar/
tar cf foo.tar a.txt b.txt
tar -cf foo.tar foo/
```

are those 3 lines of commands the same as this?

```
tar cf foo.tar foo/
```

Comment: Is this really a programming question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, yes.

Since, in the group of three, you're creating the archive file fresh each time with the `c` or `-c` option, only the last one will matter <sup>(a)</sup>.

So it comes down to whether the following two are equivalent:

```
tar -cf foo.tar foo/
tar  cf foo.tar foo/
```

and they are: the `-` in front of the `c` is optional.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Unless you have set up your directory permissions and `umask` settings in such a bizarre way that you can create files but not overwrite them :-)

Comment: +1 for the footnote's thoroughness ^^  (and yes, "c" in tar will create the archive and clobber any pre-existing one as it does so) (on 'recent' versions of tar, you may have "-k" or "--keep-files" to allow adding to pre-existing content... but this is NOT portable)